# selecting a specific container without a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having problems with my coding-challange where im not allowed to use `:nth-child`, +, ~ or the data-target in the css. I also cannot edit the HTML. Is there any solution to get the second element in the `<section>` without the syntax above?
Thanks for the help

```
<article id="task-2">
        <div class="marble"></div>
        <section>
          <div class="marble"></div>
          <div class="marble" data-target></div>
        </section>
        <div class="marble"></div>
      </article>
```

Comment: `:last-child()`, `:nth-last-child()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't use `nth-child`, the closest to it that you can select is `nth-of-type`, so you can do the following:

```css
section div {
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px yellow;
}
section div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<article id="task-2">
        <div class="marble"></div>
        <section>
          <div class="marble"></div>
          <div class="marble" data-target></div>
        </section>
        <div class="marble"></div>
      </article>
```

Read more about this selector here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: We are not supposed to use :nth-child.

Comment: @AbhilashAsokan: then it’s super convenient that this answer *doesn’t* use `:nth-child()`.